# Класс ObservableCollection<T> и функция IndexOf

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Добрый день столкнулся с такой проблемой: функция IndexOf класса ObservableCollection всегда возвращает -1.
Вот код:

```
ObservableCollection<Item> FilterMask = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
foreach(Worker w in ListWorker)
    {
        if(w.Directions.Count == 0) continue;
        Item ForFilter = new Item() { Text = w.Directions[0], IsSelected = true };
        if (FilterMask.IndexOf(ForFilter) == -1)
            FilterMask.Add(ForFilter);
    }
```

Пример класса Item:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
        }
    }

    bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelected = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

В FilterMask появляются дубликаты, чего не должно быть согласно коду=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разумеется, возвращает `-1`.
Ты создаёшь новый объект класса Item и ищешь его в коллекции. Он туда ещё не добавлен. Если ты хочешь, чтобы твой код работал, перегрузи в `Item` методы [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx). Или полноценно реализуй интерфейс [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Достаточно будет перегрузить только метод Equals? После его перегрузки код стал работать как надо.

Comment: @S.Matorykin: Нет. Класс, у которого перегружен Equals, но не GetHashCode, поломан, и приведёт к неожиданным проблемам в неожиданных местах. Причём, возможно, не сразу.

Comment: Да, вляпался в это в реальной жизни. Объект из коллекции не находится в этой же самой коллекции. Всё потому, что разработчик забыл перегрузить метод `GetHashCode`.